# How can I call parent list item by clicking on child list item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a list view by clicking on the item in list view i will get another child list view . how can I get positions of parent list view by clicking on child items

Main Activity :

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    newListitems2.clear();

    newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

    dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
    dialog.show();

    listView1.setTag(position);
    list1 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

    ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, newListitems2);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Parent List :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    String item = null, qty = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
        holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    parentobjid = newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
    if (!parentobjid.isEmpty()) {
        holder.name.setText("   " + newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
        holder.qty.setText("      " + String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                .getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
    } else {
        holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Child ListAdapter :

```
if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
        holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    parentobjid = newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
    if (!parentobjid.isEmpty()) {
        holder.name.setText(" " + newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
        holder.qty.setText(" " + String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
    } else {
        holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();//Cast object to integer
                newListitems.get(pos).setChecked(!newListitems.get(pos).isChecked());
            }
        });
        if (newListitems.get(position).isChecked()) {
            holder.name.setEnabled(true);
            holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));

        } else {
            holder.name.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
```

Comment: do you mean expandable list view?

Comment: when i click on the item in the ;list now am getting same list as child list now i need by clicking on child item i have to disable parent item

Answer (score 0):

create two list object like

```
List<String> list_parent;
List<String> list_child;
```

on parent item click update `list_child` and assign to `listview Adapter` and set one `flag` for which listview is displaying (like set `flag` `0` if `list_parent` assign to adapter and 1 for child)

`onBackPressed` check if flag is 1 then assign `list_parent` to adapter and if flag is 0 then `finish();`

But remember every-time when you assign list object to adapter call  `notifyDataSetChanged`

This is simple Listview code:

```
 public class ListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;
    int flag=0;//parent
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values_parent = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 
                                         "Android Example List View" 
                                        };

        String[] values_child= new String[] { "Child 1", 
              "Child 2",
              "Child 3",
              "Child 4"
             };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values_parent);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

               // ListView Clicked item index
               int itemPosition     = position;

              if(flag=0)
               {
                flag=1;
                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values_child);
                }
                else
                    {
                 flag=0;
                   }

              }

         }); 
    }



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(flag=0)
     finish();
   else{
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values_parent);
      }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have two different parent and child objects?

Comment: i have two adapters for list view but having same data becoze by cliking item in parent i want to get same list as child list with check boxs

Comment: i kept disable logic but it is working in child list not in parent list please help mee

Comment: how can it possible i use here 2 base adapters

Comment: Use single adapter and just change list when required and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: try to bind your adapter to listview inside flag if else if(flag=0)
               {
                flag=1;
                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values_child);
                }